# Searching specific character in file in powershell not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have list of files in my folder. I need to only extract the files which has ~ sign. So, I tried:

```
'dore_20220319121423~'.contains('~')
```

Output is coming as `'True'`.

But when I scanned whole folder and tried to find such files then the filter is not working.All the files inside the folder are coming in output, since I needed only the files having `~` sign.

```
cls
$folerPath = 'Z:\Splite\RMQ\2022-03-20'
$files = Get-ChildItem $folerPath
foreach ($f in $files){
$outfile = $f.Name.Contains('~')
if ($outfile){
echo $files.Name
}
}
```

I am seeing all the files in output, even though I applied filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking the `~` character but are only passing it to `$outfile`

Try doing:

```
foreach ($f in $files){
   if ($f.Name.Contains('~')){
       echo $f.Name
   }
}
```

Comment: no it didn't worked. outfile is boolean here

Comment: Variable should be $f inside the foreach, see codeblock